# Will mysql somehow rerun killed query behind my back?

Tags: mysql

I ran a very unique experimental long query about 1 week ago from Sequel Pro against a MySQL 5.5 DB. The query is not used in any codes; just a manual one. I remember I killed it after only a few seconds. Then in the last few days, the DBA keeps finding the exact same query was started again after one being killed. The DBA has verified the query was killed at the time he tried. My workstation has been rebooted at least once and moved out of network connection many times since I first ran that query manually. Sequel Pro had no connection to any DB when one of this rerun occurred. And there seems nothing else in my workstation that would trigger that.

My question: is there some way that the query can get stuck in some server-side job/run list and not being killed properly but get rerun?

Answer (score 0):

Found the cause. A DBA has cron script running in the background looking for slow queries in the slow query log and try to run explain on the query! Apparently the slow queries get rerun again and again.